# Trouble with sort() functions in PHP

Tags: php, sorting

I am trying to sort an array I have in PHP and for some reason all I get in return is "1" when I attempt to use any of the `sort()` functions. Here is the code I have so far:

```
$files = glob('Some\Random\Directory\*.txt');
$tag = array();
foreach($files as $file){
$fh = fopen($file, 'rb');
while($col = fgetcsv($fh)) {
if (isset($tag[$col[2]])) {
   $tag[$col[2]]++;}
else {
   $tag[$col[2]] = 1;}}
fclose($fh);}
print_r($tag);
```

Which results in displaying my array as expected. However, when I attempt to do:

```
echo arsort($tag);
```

All I get in return on the page is "1."

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Even if that worked - it would print "Array".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array [`sort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) functions work on a reference of the array. As such they don't return the sorted array but `true` (1) or `false` (0).

```
print_r($tag);
arsort($tag);
print_r($tag);
```

Comment: Perfect, that worked great. I read in the API about `sort()` only referencing the array but must have missed the part about it returning `true` or `false`. Thanks for the help!